# How to keep the list window when clicking an item in the ant-design submenu

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, antd

In the code below, when the cursor of **`Menu2`** is placed, the item of **`Menu2`** is displayed through the **`hover event.`**

And if you click an **`item of Menu2`**, the applied hover event is canceled and the window showing the **`item of Menu2`** is hidden.

In this situation, how can I make the submenu window remain visible even after clicking the **`item in Menu2`**?

```
import React from "react";
import { Menu } from "antd";

const App = () => (
  <Menu mode="horizontal">
    <Menu.Item key="mail">Menu1</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.SubMenu key="SubMenu" title="Menu2">
      // I want to show the submenu items of Menu2 even when I click Sub Menu1.
      <Menu.Item key="two">Sub Menu1</Menu.Item>
      // I want to show the submenu items of Menu2 even when I click Sub Menu2.
      <Menu.Item key="three">Sub Menu2</Menu.Item>
    </Menu.SubMenu>
  </Menu>
);
export default App;
```

Comment: You need to make this menu as controlled component. Use `selectedKeys`, `onSelect` & `onDeselect` prop. Follow the [Menu API](https://ant.design/components/menu/#components-menu-demo-switch-mode) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the reply it was a big help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using stopPropagation.

```
  const moreAlertBtn = useCallback((e) => {        
    e?.stopPropagation();
    setAlertLimit((prev) => prev + 5); 
  }, []);
```